# i want to select start with certain letter using regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

i have c# project and
i have following string and want to choice only start with certain letter
like 'A' and 'D'

```
SelectSeat('SID9', '1', '', 'Abc good', '265', '001')">

SelectSeat('SID0', '2', '1층', 'Dhello', '41', '003')">

SelectSeat('SID0', '2', '1층', 'Cold', '41', '003')">
```

so what i want to match result is

```
SelectSeat('SID9', '1', '', 'Abc good', '265', '001')">

SelectSeat('SID0', '2', '1층', 'Dhello', '41', '003')">
```

because this one have 'Cold' word and start with 'C'

```
SelectSeat('SID0', '2', '1층', 'Cold', '41', '003')">
```

this is what i done until now and some struggle to find help .

```
SelectSeat\('SID[0-9]*',.'([\w]*)',.'([\w\s]*)',.'([\w\s]*)'.*?\)
```

thanks!

Comment: Do you want to get the full string/line or do you need to extract some particular values from each matched line?

Comment: Also, can you tell us more about the pattern of each value inside `SelectSeat`? For example I see the 1st one starts with `SID` and is followed by one (or more?) digits

Comment: @RuiJarimba i  want to match whole this sentence SelectSeat('SID0', '2', '1층', 'start with A or D word', '41', '003')" thanks

Comment: @RuiJarimba yes that correct after SID word 1 digit following

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/iap8D4/2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i checked but it only matched start with 'Cold' phrase. sorry if i mistake thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get started with certain letter like `'A'` and `'D'`

You can try this pattern.

```
SelectSeat\('SID[0-9]',.'[0-9]',.'(.)*',\s*'([AD])(.*)',.'([\w\s]*)'.*?\)
```

using `linq`  with `Regex.IsMatch` function to get your expection string.

**Code**

```
List<string> inputs = new List<string>() {
    @"SelectSeat('SID9', '1', '', 'Abc good', '265', '001')"">",
    @"SelectSeat('SID0', '2', '1층', 'Dhello', '41', '003')"">",
    @"SelectSeat('SID0', '2', '1층', 'Cold', '41', '003')"">"
};
string pattern = @"SelectSeat\('SID[0-9]',.'[0-9]',.'(.)*',\s*'([AD])(.*)',.'([\w\s]*)'.*?\)";
var result = inputs.Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x, pattern));

foreach (var item in result)
{
     Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lyWxx0)

Comment: `/([AD])(.*)/`  This can select any word having `A` or `D` not the word starting with  `A`  or `D`.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[A]|^[a]|^[D]|^[d]/
```

Will match any word starting with A or D.